# regular expression syntax in search()

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code for matching 9 in every element:

```
import re
list=['guru99 get', 'guru99 give','guru selenium']
for element in list:
    x=re.search(r'\b9',element)
    print(x.group())
```

...but this is showing this error

```
print(x.group())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because your `search` returns no match and so `x` is `None`. According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

> Return `None` if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

You have no match (already in the first string) because all your "9" are preceded by a letter or a digit, which means those "9" do not follow a break in the chain of alphanumerical characters. So `\b9` does not occur at all in your first string.

There would be a match if the string had ".9", or "-9", or " 9", but sequences like "u9" or "99" do not match.

Maybe you tried to match a "9" that is not preceded by another digit? Then use `(?<!\d)9` as pattern.